# Select only this id's where on specific condition

Tags: mysql

I need to select only this `mes_id` where `stan` is `SG30` but it can't show `mes_id` if there is any row where `mes_id` have `stan` anything else.

I have something like this (in real I have more then 50 `stan` different values):
[image]

So at the end result shoudl show only `mes_id: 1,3,5` because `1,3,5 mes_id` have only `SG30` value in column `stan`.

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, the expected result corresponding to that data, and your attempts

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the simplest query would be:

SELECT mes_id FROM <table_name> GROUP BY mes_id HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(stan) = 'SG30'

Answer (score 0):

select mes_id from [table_name] where stan = 'SG3'

Comment: mes_id result will be: `1,2,3,4,5,6`. What I expect is `1,3,5` (because this `mes_id` have only one value in stan column : `SG30`)